# docker-compose variable substitution / interpolation with list, map, or array value

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I use variable substitution for a list, map, or array value in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

For example:

```
graylog:
  image: graylog2/server2
  extra_hosts: ${EXTRA_HOSTS}
```

and

```
export EXTRA_HOSTS="['host1:10.10.10.1','host2:10.10.10.2']"
```

gives the following error: `graylog.extra_hosts must be a mapping`

I've tried different variations of the above with no luck.

I do see that there's an open issue about this here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4249

Is it just not possible? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least as of this time (June 2018), Docker still doesn't support this. I was able to work around the issue utilizing `envsubst`.

`envsubst` is part of `gettext` and it can be used to replace only environment variables you tell it to.

Tweak the `docker-compose.yml` value to look like an array or map (either brackets or curly braces) but have the value be an environment variable.

For example

```
graylog:
  image: graylog2/server2
  extra_hosts: [ ${EXTRA_HOSTS} ]
```

Then, define your environment variable without brackets or curly braces.

For example:

```
export EXTRA_HOSTS="'host1:10.10.10.1','host2:10.10.10.2'"
```

Then utilize `envsubst`

```
envsubst '${EXTRA_HOSTS}' < docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.subst.yml && docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.subst.yaml foobar
```

Notice that you pass `'${EXTRA_HOSTS}'` to `envsubst`. This tells it to only replace this environment variable. This ensures it doesn't accidentally replace some other variable that's utilizing the variable substitution syntax of Docker compose files.

Comment: Any news about this feature without having to use envsubst?

Comment: `docker-compose` is primary meant for testing purpose. Better use `docker run` with proper arguments, and associative arrays in a bash script if required.