# Docker-Compose YAML: how to populate single-line array from environment variable?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I need to define the array of exposed ports for a given service from an environment variable.

If I define the ports array as below, it works without problems:

```
services:
  open-connect:
    ports: ["80:80","90:90"]
```

or

```
services:
  open-connect:
    ports: ['80:80','90:90']
```

However, if I define it in a .env file

```
EXPOSED_PORTS="'80:80','90:90'"
```

or

```
EXPOSED_PORTS='"80:80","90:90"'
```

---

```
services:
  open-connect:
    ports: [$EXPOSED_PORTS]
```

It gives me the error:

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.override.yml' is invalid because:
services.open-connect.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

It only works if the environment variable contains a single port mapping:

```
EXPOSED_PORTS="80:80"
```

How can I make this array of exposed ports configurable from an environment variable?

**Update**

The suggested similar question [docker-compose variable substitution / interpolation with list, map, or array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919605/docker-compose-variable-substitution-interpolation-with-list-map-or-array-va) is a bit old (2018) and doesn't provide a solution supported by docker-compose on its own; instead, it requires to use an external command to physically alter the docker-compose file with the array value.

Comment: I don't know if this is still valid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50933489/10651696

Answer (score 2):

It is little bit tricky but closer solution to what you want to do.

You may inject ports as second `docker-compose` file passed from `STDIN`.

Let's say that we have `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: 'test:v0.1'
```

and variable `PORTS`:

```bash
$ export PORTS='"1:1","2:2"'
$ echo $PORTS
"1:1","2:2"
```

Let's check config with `STDIN` injection:

```bash
printf "version: '3'\nservices:\n  web:\n    ports: [${PORTS}]\n" | docker-compose -f /dev/stdin -f docker-compose.yml config
```

output:

```
services:
  web:
    image: test:v0.1
    ports:
    - 1:1/tcp
    - 2:2/tcp
version: '3.0'
```

As you can see we injected

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    ports: ["1:1","2:2"]
```

part from command line

---

Also multiple ports may be simply set via `"80-90:80-90"` syntax (all 10 ports will be forwarded).

Comment: Nice. Notice that if you want to run this porgramatically, you could change the prinf for an echo,